# system.out.println(""); syntax error

Tags: java

Comecei a aprender Java com o Elipse e estou aprendendo cada dia mais. Mas me deparei com uma situação: quando uso o `system.out.println("");` , o Eclipse "diz" que há erro de sintaxe e eu não tenho a menor ideia do que pode ser isso. Já tentei usar o *shortcut* "syso" + Ctrl+ Espaço mas nem aparece a opção. Procurei por respostas nesse e outros sites mas não encontrei o meu problema.

A versão do Eclipse que uso é o Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers (Mars).

Irei postar uma imagem mostrando o *syntax error* que aparece juntamente com o código.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agradeço desde já! Obrigado pela atenção.

Código abaixo:

```
package cadastro;
// 08
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import dados.Cliente;
import dados.Produto;
import dados.Venda;
import utilitarios.Console;

public class Cadastro {

    public static HashMap<String, Cliente> listaCliente = new HashMap<>();
    public static HashMap<Integer, Produto> listaProduto = new HashMap<>();
    public static HashMap<Integer, Venda> listaVenda = new HashMap<>();

    public static void  incluirCliente (Cliente obj ) {
        listaCliente.put(obj.getCpf(), obj);
    }

    public static void excluirCliente (Cliente obj) {
        listaCliente.remove(obj);
    }

    public static ArrayList<Cliente> pesqClienteCpf (String cpf) {
        ArrayList<Cliente> resposta = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Cliente obj : listaCliente.values()) {
            if (obj.getCpf().contains(cpf)){
                resposta.add(obj);
            }
        }
        return resposta;
    }
     // 11
    public static ArrayList<Cliente> pesqClienteNome(String nome) {
        ArrayList<Cliente> resposta = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Cliente obj : listaCliente.values()) {
            if (obj.getNome().contains(nome)) {
                resposta.add(obj);
            }
        }
        return resposta;
    }

    public static void incluirProduto (Produto obj) {
        listaProduto.put(obj.getCodigo(), obj);
    }

    public static void excluirProduto (Produto obj) {
        listaProduto.remove(obj.getCodigo());
    }

    public static ArrayList<Produto> pesqProdutoCodigo (int produto) {
        ArrayList<Produto> resposta = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Produto obj : listaProduto.values()) {
            if (obj.getCodigo() ==  produto) {
                resposta.add(obj);
            }
        }
        return resposta;
    }

    public static void incluirVenda (Venda obj) {
        listaVenda.put(obj.getNumVenda(), obj);
    }

    public static void excluirVenda (Venda obj) {
        listaVenda.remove(obj.getNumVenda());
    }
    system.out.println("asdasd");
}
```

Comment: O correto é `System.out.println`. A classe `System` é com o S maiuculo.

Comment: Ainda continua com o mesmos erro. :/

Comment: O que você pretende com esse comando? Ele é inutil no seu código, simplesmente remova-o.

Comment: Eu sei que era inútil, só não estava entendendo porque que dava o erro. Mas agora eu entendi, desculpe pela pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java é uma linguagem case sensitive.
Palavras com letras maiúsculas e minúsculas fazem diferença.

**Correto:** `System.out.println("asdasd");`

**Errado:** `system.out.println("asdasd");`

Quando puder, pesquise por Java Conventions no Google, você irá entender como são nomeados os campos, classes, variáveis e aprenderá sobre as boas práticas e padrões de nomes...

Answer (score 3):

Você está chamando o método no corpo da **classe**, por isso o alerta. Chame `System.out.println("");` dentro de algum método ou construtor da sua classe `Cadastro`.

Answer (score 1):

seu problema é bem simples e que acontece com a maioria das pessoas que começam no mundo Java.

O método System.out.println(""); começa com o "S" maiusculo da Classe System. Tente com "S" maiusculo e vai adiantar.

Comment: Esse é só um dos problemas.

Comment: Já tentei com S maisculo e também colocar em outras partes do código, mas continua a mesma coisa.

Comment: Você colocou ele fora de um método, desse jeito também não irá funcionar.